# End of line lex

Tags: flex-lexer, lex

I am writing an interpreter for assembly using lex and yacc. The problem is that I need to parse a word that will strictly be at the end of the file. I've read that there is an anchor `$`, which can help. However it doesn't work as I expected. I've wrote this in my lex file:

```
ABC$    {printf("QWERTY\n");}
```

The input file is:

```
ABC
```

without spaces or any other invisible symbols. So I expect the outputput to be QWERTY, however what I get is:

```
ABC
```

which I guess means that the program couldn't parse it. Then I thought, that `$` might be a regular symbol in lex, so I changed the input file into this:

```
ABC$
```

So, if `$` isn't a special symbol, then it will be parsed as a normal symbol, and the output will be QWERTY. This doesn't happen, the output is:

```
ABC$
```

The question is whether `$` in lex is a normal symbol or special one.

Comment: Your code prints QWERTY for me when I enter ABC and a newline as the input. Does your file maybe contain a carriage return before the newline even though you're not on Windows (or you are on Windows, but opening the file in binary mode)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In (f)lex, `$` matches zero characters *followed by a newline character*.

That's different from many regex libraries where `$`  will match at the end of input. So if your file does not have a newline at the end, as your question indicates (assuming you consider newline to be an invisible character), it won't be matched.

As @sepp2k suggests in a comment, the pattern also won't be matched if the input file happens to use Windows line endings (which consist of the sequence `\r\n`), unless the generated flex file was compiled for Windows. So if you created the file on Windows and run the flex-generated scanner in a Unix environment, the `\r` will also cause the pattern to fail to match. In that case, you can use (f)lex's trailing context operator:

```
ABC/\r?\n   { puts("Matched ABC at the end of a line"); }
```

See the [flex documentation for patterns](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html) for a full description of the trailing context operator. (Search for "trailing context" on that page; it's roughly halfway down.) `$` is *exactly* equivalent to `/\n`.

That still won't match `ABC` at the very end of the file. Matching strings at the very end of the file is a bit tricky, but it can be done with two patterns if it's ok to recognise the string other than at the end of the file, triggering a different action:

```
ABC/.    { /* Do nothing. This ABC is not at the end of a line or the file */ }
ABC      { puts("ABC recognised at the end of a line"); }
```

That works because the first pattern will match as long as there is some non-newline character following `ABC`. (`.` matches any character other than a newline. See the above link for details.) If you also need to work with Windows line endings, you'll need to modify the trailing context in the first pattern.