# Matching token only if it's on a line by itself in flex

Tags: c, flex-lexer

I want a flex lexer to have a special case for the `q` token in that it is recognized as such only if it's the only thing on a line aside from whitespace.  Given:

```
S            [ \f\r\t\v]

%%

^{S}*q{S}*$  { exit(0); }
```

That does *not* match the `q`.  If I remove the trailing `$`, then it matches; but then it also matches things like `q foo`, i.e., `q` *not* on a line by itself.

Why doesn't the `$` work?  And how can I get what I want?

---

FYI:

```
$ flex --version
flex 2.6.4 Apple(flex-34)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [End of line lex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56102786/end-of-line-lex)

Comment: @PiotrSiupa Probably, but if I used that solution and `^{S}*q/.`, I'd want to `REJECT` that (because I'd then want it to match the general case of an identifier farther down in the `.l` file), but then it would just match `^{S}*q{S}*` and I'm back to where I started.

Comment: Although if I define `NS [^ \f\r\t\v]` then do `^{S}*q{S}*{NS}` first, I can return an error token.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem (it "works for me") — but the information needed to justify this observation is bigger than fits in a comment.

With this variant of your code:

```
%option noinput
%option nounput
%option noyywrap

S            [ \f\r\t\v]

%%

^{S}*q{S}*$  { printf("Quit!\n"); exit(0); }

%%

int main(void)
{
    yylex();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled on macOS Monterey 12.6.3 with Flex 2.6.4 Apple(flex-34), I get output such as:

```
$ flex61
Absolute
Absolute
 Aquaduct
 Aquaduct
  Q  !
  Q  !
  q  !
  q  !
  q   
Quit!
$
```

That looks like the behaviour you were looking for.  There are trailing blanks at the end of the "`q` on its own" line but a line containing only `q` also terminates the program with the `Quit!` message.  I compiled it with the commands:

```
flex flex61.l
clang -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
      -fno-common -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-nullability-completeness -o flex61 lex.yy.c
```

The `-Wno-nullability-completeness` is necessary to suppress a large number of obnoxious warnings from `<stdio.h>`; the `-Wno-sign-compare` avoids one problem in the generated C code.

```
$ clang --version
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
$
```

---

Possible causes of the trouble:

- You have more rules in your code that interfere with this one.

  - You might fix that by ensuring this rule is the first rule.
  - This is my best guess.
- You aren't working with the code you think you're working with.

  - Make changes such as adding 'printf("Quit!\n"):`before the`exit(0);` to demonstrate that the code you're editing is the code being compiled and executed.
  - Unless you're using the Xcode IDE, this is probably not the trouble.

Comment: It's not the first rule, but it's pretty near the top and no rules before it are even close. I guess for some reason in my case, a `\n` isn't being included in the string that would make `$` not match.